# UISearchBar stays when seguing to another view controller via push

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uisearchbar

I followed this guide: http://www.jhof.me/simple-uisearchcontroller-implementation/

The only difference in my code is

instead of `self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;`

I have `self.navigationItem.titleView = self.searchController.searchBar;`

When I segue from the results table view controller, the uisearchbar stays in the navigation bar.

Comment: as you add search bar to navigation bar as its title view, search bar always stays in the navigation bar is expected

Comment: But when i segue from the first tableView, it disappears, only when i segue from the results tableview after searching it stays

Comment: now I see what you want. see my answer

Answer (score 0):

I rewrite the sample from Apple, you can see I comment `self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;` then set it to navigation bar's title view, just like you. You can find search bar is here in snapshot.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    APLResultsTableController *qresultsTableController = [[APLResultsTableController alloc] init];
    self.resultsTableController = qresultsTableController;
    _searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:qresultsTableController];
    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
    [self.searchController.searchBar sizeToFit];
//    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;
    self.navigationItem.titleView = self.searchController.searchBar;
    self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = NO;

    // we want to be the delegate for our filtered table so didSelectRowAtIndexPath is called for both tables
    self.resultsTableController.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.searchController.delegate = self;
    self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO; // default is YES
    self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self; // so we can monitor text changes + others

    // Search is now just presenting a view controller. As such, normal view controller
    // presentation semantics apply. Namely that presentation will walk up the view controller
    // hierarchy until it finds the root view controller or one that defines a presentation context.
    //
    self.definesPresentationContext = YES;  // know where you want UISearchController to be displayed
}
```

snapshot is here,

[image]

UISearchBarController has a property named `hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation` default is YES, set it to NO if you want to use it as navigation item's title view

```
self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = NO;
```

I have tested, it works. hope it helpful.

Comment: i have that already set to NO. yet it still stays in the nav bar when i segue from the results tableview

Comment: @farhan There is a sample about UISearchController from Apple, I rewrite some simple code based on it, I post it into my answer, it do the same thing you want to do and works.

Comment: Do i put that code in the initial tableview or results?

Comment: I got it to work just by adding   `vc.tableView.delegate = self;` `vc` being the resultsTableViewController